# Как поставить защиту от многократного нажатия на кнопку?

Tags: php, mysql

Вообще такая беда: у меня есть форма, когда человек нажимает на кнопку быстро много раз, то запросы у меня тоже отправляются много раз сразу. Ну вот как поставить защиту, чтобы выводилась ошибка, когда много раз нажимает?

Comment: [Вам сюда][1]


  [1]: http://2med.org/index.php/Тремор

Answer (score 5):

Запретить нажатие на кнопку можно:
    1. Средствами JS
    2. Ставить на сервере таймаут принятия запросов от клиента
    3. Проверять входящие данные и запрещать дубляж

Плюс ещё уйма способов. Было бы круто, если бы вы подробнее описали.

Answer (score 3):

На `js + jquery` вот так:

```
$(function () {
    $('.once').one('submit', function () {
        $(this).submit(function () {
            return false;
        });            
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/P7g7m/

Без `jquery` вот так:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var nodelist = document.getElementsByClassName('once');
    for (var i = 0; i < nodelist.length; i++) {
        nodelist[i].onclick = function () {
            this.onclick = function () {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/P7g7m/2/

Comment: а что именно она делает?

Comment: перехватываем submit формы, как перехватили, выставляем новый перехватчик (return false), который не дает сделать сабмит еще раз. можно наверное для красоты [еще и всё  задизэблить](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/P7g7m/4/)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!--Смысл в том, что кнопка будет работать только когда будет введена верная каптча, соответственно подряд 3-4 раза её не получится нажать-->

<script>
  var a = Math.ceil (Math.random () * 99), b = Math.ceil (Math.random () * 9), c = a + b;
  document.write ( + a + ' + ' + b + ' = ');
</script>
<input class="input" maxlength="3" size="2" onfocus="document.getElementById ('button').disabled = 0"onblur="document.getElementById ('button').disabled = !(this.value == c)" />
        
<input class="button-submit" type="submit" id="button" value="ОТПРАВИТЬ" disabled="disabled"/>
```